# CSV to multi dimensional array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, csv, ms-word

I am currently making a macro for a word template that is supposed to ask for a CSV holding all the data for the variables in the word document. After you're done choosing the CSV holding the data, its supposed to check what services the client has (based on the informaiton in the CSV), and then edit the word template accordingly. By edit I mean that it removes a part of the template containging specific services that the client doesn't have access to.

I'm currently stuck at figuring how to read the CSV in the best way to determine the Word template's shape.

Would it be possible to do this by making a 2D array and then determine the shape of the template by checking what array cells are empty and not? Or is there a better way I dont know about?

This is my code as of now:

```
Sub Jagvilldö()
    'choose data (csv file)
    Dim intChoice As Integer
    Dim strPath As String

    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False

    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

    If intChoice <> 0 Then
        'filepath is saved in strPath
        strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    Debug.Print strPath
```

After this code, I want to control the selected CSV - to determine the template's shape. This is that code as of now:

```
'import csv and convert to 2-Dimensional array

'defining string variables
Dim rowString As String
Dim rowArray() As String
Dim myfile() As String
Dim finalArray(0, 0) As String
Dim fileNumber As Long
fileNumber = FreeFile
Dim i As Integer
Open strPath For Input As fileNumber
Dim p As Integer

i = 0
Do While Not EOF(fileNumber)
    Debug.Print "In EOF"

    Line Input #fileNumber, rowString
    rowArray() = Split(rowString, ",")

    If i = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "In If"

        For p = 0 To 19
            Debug.Print "In loop: " & p
            'this is where I suspect I am getting my error
            finalArray(p, i) = rowArray(p)
        Next p
    End If

    finalArray(0, i) = rowArray(i)
    i = i + 1
Loop
Close #fileNumber
Debug.Print finalArray(0, 0)
```

With this code I am getting the error: "Index out of proportion" in the `For` loop inside the `If i = 0`.

This is the outpput I am getting before the error occurs:

[image: This is the output I am getting before the error occurs]

Maybe you can see what I'm trying to do?

And also, since I'm already at it: would it be possible to automatically merge the template with the CSV without having to prompt trough it manually?

Comment: The answer to "would it be possible to ..." questions is practically always "yes". What have you tried to make this work? What does not work?

Comment: As of now I've further developed my code to where im getting a very weird error, should i post a new question about it or should we further discuss it in private?

Comment: If you want personal support: I can provide you with my employer's contact details. For help on SO you're supposed to provide a [mcve], including all errors you're getting from that code.

Comment: You're defining a fixed-size 1x1 array (`Dim finalArray(0, 0)`). Either define the array with the correct size, or use `ReDim finalArray(0, 0)` to make the array resizable. In the latter case you still need to resize the array before adding another value, though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, would it work if I'd set it to be huge but not fill all of it?

Comment: Tried it and it seems to work, I will perform further testing of my program and then maybe come back to you, have a good day sir.

Comment: It's certainly possible to "oversize" the array, but you'll be wasting memory by doing so. OTOH, resizing the array is not the best option performance-wise (if you have lots of data), because each resize will create a new array, copy the data, then replace the previous array.

Comment: I dont really have lots of data, the biggest csv is about 20x15.

Comment: Then the best approach would probably be to read your data into memory, determine the dimensions of the matrix from the data, and then define the array via `ReDim finalArray(sizeX, sizeY)`.